# Detect click on focus out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following cshtml:

```
<input class="mdl-textfield__input AddressCity geo-city required text-box single-line" id="city" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off">

<span class="mdl-textfield__error cityWarning" style="visibility: hidden; color: dodgerblue; display: none;">This city is not from Google Api</span>

<div class="pac-container pac-logo" style="width: 96px; position: absolute; left: 993px; top: 307px; display: none;">
</div>
```

And the following JS:

```
$("body").on("focusout", ".geo-city", function (e) {
var city = $(this).val();
var apiElem = $(this).closest('div').find('.pac-container').length;
var apiItem = 0;
if (apiElem > 0) {
    apiItem = $(this).closest('div').find('.pac-container').find('.pac-item').length;
}

var apiValue = $(this).closest('div').find('.fromApi').val();
if (city != "") {
        if (apiValue != city) {
                $(this).closest('div').find('.cityWarning').css('display', 'flex');
                $(this).closest('div').find('.cityWarning').css('visibility', 'visible');

        } else {
            $(this).closest('div').find('.cityWarning').css('display', 'none');
            $(this).closest('div').find('.cityWarning').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
} else {
    $(this).closest('div').find('.cityWarning').css('display', 'none');
    $(this).closest('div').find('.cityWarning').css('visibility', 'hidden');
}
```

});

The pac-container is from the Google Api autocomplete.

What I want to do is that upon focus out on the city input, check if the click is on the pac-container div.  If that is the case the hide the span cityWarning else show it.

Any idea of how I can do this?

Comment: Do you mean to check **which next element** gets the focus as you tab away or focus out from the city input? if so, maybe try inspecting `document.activeElement` on focus out.

Comment: @jom : Kind of yes.  I need to which click has caused the focusout.  If it is a click on the pac-container div

Comment: you can check for event.currentTarget to know where the focus is going to..

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt: no, the currentTarget is the city input itself.

Comment: @tabby Why don't you hide the `cityWarning` span on focusout and check `focusin` on the `div.pac-container`.

Comment: @jom :  I tried this does not work..

Comment: @tabby Be sure to add `tabindex` on the `div.pac-container` so it can receive focus.

Comment: @jom : This div pac-container is generated by google api.  I am not sure if I can do this.

Comment: @tabby Then check focus in on the elements inside of this pac-container, like: `$(document.body).on('focusin', '.pac-container input, function () { .... })`.